# Post xml using HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, post

I have a problem with passing xml file from client to api. I use HttpClient to connect.
My code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        /*var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InitUploadType));
        serializer.Serialize(data);*/
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("initupload-sign.xml");

        WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("cert.crt");
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);


        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test-e-dokumenty.mf.gov.pl");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<XmlDocument>("/api/Storage/InitUploadSigned", doc).Result;

        return response.ToString();
```

I am receiving Bad Request 400.

Comment: You can use a tool like fiddler to see what is sent/received from the client. It will help you to figure out what is happening because an HTTP 400 error can mean a lot of things.

Comment: I went to the url https://test-e-dokumenty.mf.gov.pl using a IE browser and did not get xml data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code I have modified?

```
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            /*var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InitUploadType));
            serializer.Serialize(data);*/
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("initupload-sign.xml");

            WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("cert.crt");
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test-e-dokumenty.mf.gov.pl");
            client.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            var response = client.UploadString(path, doc.OuterXml);

            return response.ToString();
```